# How to UseCookieAuthentication OR ClaimsIdentity between ASP.NET Identity Owin site and ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP.NET web application that is using ASP.NET Identity for login with UseCookieAuthentication in the Startup.
The login site is working fine.
I also have an ASP.NET WebAPI site that I use to gather data.  I would like to secure the WebAPI with the same cookie that was created at the Login web site.
The machine keys are identical and the UseCookieAuthentication is using the same CookieName and CookieDomain settings.

I can't seem to find any good articles on how to use Cookie based auth between ASP.NET sites.

Any links or ideas are welcome.

If there are any examples passing ClaimsIdentity between two sites that would be great.
We only choose the UseCookieAuthentication because it was similar to FormsAuthentication but we are not opposed to using Claims Authentication if we could find out how.

**Working by adding**

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for the above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ClaimsIdentity instead of trying to pass around cookies.  That way you can "register" the web application with the WebAPI application.

I'm assuming by the description that the web app and the WebAPI app are on different domains or at least different virtual directories on the server.  If so, you'll probably want to take a look at CORS as well.

Here are a few relevant articles:
http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/25/securing-asp-net-web-api-endpoints-using-owin-oauth-2-0-and-claims/

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

If the web app is the only consumer of the WebAPI code and they can be hosted on the same server, you may consider just adding the WebAPI code to the web app solution.  Then you won't have to worry about CORS.

Comment: This are both good articles but the Claims based article is all about using a custom OAuthProvider but I am using the ASP.NET Identity Entity Framework provider.  Adding app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); to my startup seems to have helped.

Comment: I would prefer the "Claims" method and not user "CORS" but I can't find any good articles on how to get this to work. Basically I can't figure out what I must do inside the startup of the WebAPI site to get a claim in the context.

Comment: Have you looked at these? http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/  or http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/